# Failed to compile Apache from source with only Mod_Proxy

Tags: apache, compilation, mod-proxy

I am trying to compile apache from source with **only module "proxy and rewrite".** Here is what I used as my configure

```
 sudo ./configure --disable-actions --disable-asis --disable-autoindex --disable-cgi --disable-cgid --disable-charset-lite --disable-dir --disable-env --disable-imap --disable-include --disable-negotiation --disable-setenvif --disable-status --disable-userdir --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-connect --enable-proxy-ftp --enable-proxy-http --enable-rewrite
```

then I was able to run make

```
sudo make
```

this is where the problem is, it ends with this error:

```
Making all in support
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/support'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/support'
/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -pthread    -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DAP_HAVE_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER   -I/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/srclib/apr/include -I/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/srclib/apr-util/include -I/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/srclib/apr-util/xml/expat/lib -I. -I/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/os/unix -I/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/server/mpm/prefork -I/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/modules/http -I/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/modules/filters -I/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/modules/proxy -I/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/include -I/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/modules/generators -I/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/modules/dav/main -export-dynamic -L/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/srclib/apr-util/xml/expat/lib   -o htdigest  htdigest.lo    /home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/srclib/pcre/libpcre.la /home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/srclib/apr-util/libaprutil-0.la /home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/srclib/apr-util/xml/expat/libexpat.la /home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/srclib/apr/libapr-0.la -lrt -lm -lcrypt -lnsl -lpthread -ldl
/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/srclib/apr-util/.libs/libaprutil-0.so: undefined reference to `crypt_r'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [htdigest] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/support'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/james/apache2/httpd-2.0.65/support'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Anybody have an idea on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why it would not compile on my Laptop (Mint 16?), but I compiled it on the linux server it worked great! Its running Debian 7